# Finding all the objects where foo.prototype instanceof bar

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, prototype, instance

How can I get a list of all the constructors whose prototypes are instances of an object (e.g `Error.prototype instanceof Object && EvalError.prototype instanceof Object`)? What I want is something like:

`> inheritors(Object)`

`[Function,  Array,  Number,  Boolean,  String,  Symbol,  Date,  Promise,  RegExp,  Error,  EvalError,  RangeError,  ReferenceError,  SyntaxError,  TypeError,  URIError,  ArrayBuffer,  Uint8Array,  Int8Array,  Uint16Array,  Int16Array,  Uint32Array,  Int32Array,  Float32Array,  Float64Array,  Uint8ClampedArray,  DataView,  Map,  Set,  WeakMap,  WeakSet, ...]`

The only solution I can think of is (try not to puke):

```
function inheritors(fn){
    return Object
      .getOwnPropertyNames(global) //use `window` if you're testing it outside of node.js
      .filter(x=>x&&global[x].prototype instanceof fn)
}
```

Ew. (It also doesn't detect quite a few things like `foo.Bar`)

I'll be grateful for a solution.

Comment: Why do you need this? And yup, that somehow looks like the only solution.

Comment: The reason I need it is complicated; basically I'm working on a genetic algorithm project (for recreational purposes), which literally includes a crude Lisp implementation (no macros though).

Comment: You can't really, it's not possible to find backreferences to an object. If you need to do this in code, starting with a list of candidates (like the globals in your snippet) and filtering them is your only choice. If you can use debugging tools, taking a memory snapshot and searching in there might work.

Comment: Thanks, I've never been good at keeping track of what the builtin methods are and aren't good for.
I guess I could make an array containing all constructors if I really needed to solve this problem.